# Which way to store resultset?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a database table with the following fields:

```
id
name
```

And I put the names in a combobox is there anyway to get the id of the selected name from database? because i want to add this id to another table in my database.
Here's the code to get the value of id from the selected item I've tried to use subqueries, but the problem is to store this id in a variable or something so i can add this id to another table.

```
String a=mycombobox.getselecteditem().toString();
String sql="select id from table1 where name='"+a"'+)";
```

Comment: There is not enough information here. We need some sort of working code that shows us the setup, and you need to show where the problem is and what you want to achieve. It's best if you [edit] the question and add a [mcve].

Comment: Just insert the retrieved String into the other table after you select it from the first table.

Comment: After i selected it from the first table it's just a resultset or executed query..i cant store it in a string to insert it again into the other table..here is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do a PreparedStatement and a ResultSet if you have a connection to the database in your application. Such as:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
String result; //could have an array of results or etc.
try {
   con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection() //or however you have your connection
   pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select id from table1 where name = ?");
   pstmt.setString(1, mycombobox.getSelectedItem().toString());
   ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next())
   {
      result = rs.getInt("id");
   }
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
   sqle.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Pstmt.setInt( , ) has two parameters..it's not working